# вывести объект из словаря

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть вот такой код, он  сортирует данные по расстоянию

```
        NSMutableDictionary* states = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [states setObject: @(betweenDistance / 1000) forKey:@"60.050043,30.345783"];
   [states setObject: @(betweenDistance4 / 1000) forKey:@"60.037389,30.322094"];
    [states setObject: @(betweenDistance5 / 1000) forKey:@"60.037329,30.322014"];
    [states setObject: @(betweenDistance3 / 1000) forKey:@"59.957387,30.324681"];

    NSArray* sortedStates = [states keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        if ([obj1 floatValue] > [obj2 floatValue])
        {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        if ([obj1 floatValue] < [obj2 floatValue])
        {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```

если их попробывать вывести так `NSLog(@"%@", sortedStates);` то выводятся координаты точки (60.050043,30.345783) а как мне вывести переменную (betweenDistance / 1000) тоже отсортированную по расстоянию? (т.е. после того как программа отсортирует от меньшего расстоянию к большему)

Comment: `objectForKey:`?

Comment: сейчас не могу проверить, но мне кажется он выдаст объект до сортировки?

Comment: ну, у вас есть отсортированный список ключей? пробегаетесь по нему и получаете значение для каждого ключа

Comment: @VladD ну он сортируется, но я не очень понимаю как, собственно NSArray* sortedStates то что нашёл в интернете, вообще он вроде как сортируется, но как не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

`keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` сортирует ключи, а вам надо отсортировать значения.

Сначала создайте массив всех значений: `NSArray *notSortedStates = [states allValues];` И уже потом его сортируйте.